# Passing value to function outside of arguments

Tags: rust, message-queue

I got a library (nannou) which [wants to call a function](https://docs.rs/nannou/0.8.0/nannou/fn.view.html) with signature `fn(&'r nannou::App, nannou::Frame) -> nannou::Frame`.

I need to pass some additional value into this function (my image buffer).

My app looks like this:

```
fn main {
    let buff = Buff::generate(..);
    nannou::view(view);
}

fn view(app: &App, frame: Frame) -> Frame {...}
```

I need to pass `buff` to `view`. I've tried to use [partial_application](https://docs.rs/partial_application/0.1.0/partial_application/), but Rust complains that `expected fn pointer, found closure`.

How can I do this? One, wrong and ugly way I knew - using a global variable.

Are there better ways? What's the best practice for that in Rust?

Comment: The problem here is that `nannou` expects a plain function pointer (`fn`). A closure that captures it's environment by definition is not a plain function pointer. You can therefore not pass any context by capturing context (that's the reason for the error message). I dont see any way around this besides `nannou` lifting the requirement from `fn` to `impl Fn` or something similar, allowing closures to be passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that we use the `view(..)` function as a callback internally to draw the graphics. So a bare minimum setup would look like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    nannou::sketch(view);
}

fn view(app: &App, frame: Frame) -> Frame {
    // Draw stuff
}
```

However you want to pass data in then we need to use a `Model` like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    nannou::app(model).update(update).run();
}

struct Model {
    my_data: MyData,
}

fn model(app: &App) -> Model {
    app
        .new_window()
        .with_dimensions(720, 720)
        .view(view)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let my_data = MyData::new();
    Model { my_data }
}

fn update(_app: &App, _model: &mut Model, _update: Update) {}

fn view(app: &App, model: &Model, frame: Frame) -> Frame {
    // Draw stuff
}
```

Notice the view function has a different signature when setup like this. It includes a `Model` which you can put your own data in. It is immutable while you want to update it in the `update()` function, but you can get around this with `RefCell` if needed.

What I normally do is launch my other threads from the `model()` function then use channels in the `Model` to communicate back to the nannou loop, like:

```rust
fn model(app: &App) -> Model {
    let (talk_to_nannou, data_from_my_thread) = mpsc::channel();
    thread::spawn(|| {
        //All the stuff I want to do
        talk_to_nannou.send("Hey");
    });
    Model {
        data_from_my_thread,
    };
}

fn view(app: &App, model: &Model, frame: Frame) -> Frame {
    if let Some(msg) = model.data_from_my_thread.try_recv() {
        dbg!(msg);
    }
}
```

You could think of it a different way if you were adding it to an existing application like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    // My awesome app that has heaps of cool stuff
    thread::spawn(|| {
        nannou::app(model).update(update).run();
    });
    // Do more stuff in my cool app
}

struct Model {
    my_data: MyData,
}

fn model(app: &App) -> Model {
    app.new_window()
        .with_dimensions(720, 720)
        .view(view)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let my_data = MyData::new();
    Model { my_data }
}

fn update(_app: &App, _model: &mut Model, _update: Update) {}

fn view(app: &App, model: &Model, frame: Frame) -> Frame {
    // Draw stuff
}
```

Then you could tuck all the nannou stuff in a module but it's kinda up to you how you want to arrange things. The only thing is nannou needs to run its internal loop to do all the work but it's happy to be on another thread.

Checkout the [examples](https://github.com/nannou-org/nannou/tree/master/examples) and [guide](https://guide.nannou.cc/) for more info

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `nannou`'s API is just very restrictive. If it used the `Fn*` traits in the callback type, you could use a closure and capture your extra argument. With the API being a function pointer, you're forced to using global state to pass the data in.

Here is another way of doing it. I'm assuming your data and function look like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct ExtraData {
    data: usize,
}

type MyViewFn = fn(app: &nannou::App, frame: nannou::Frame, extra: &mut ExtraData) -> nannou::Frame;

fn my_callback(app: &nannou::App, frame: nannou::Frame, extra: &mut ExtraData) -> nannou::Frame {
    println!("{:?}", extra);
    frame
}

fn main() {
    call_view_with(my_callback, ExtraData { data: 42 });
}
```

That is, `call_view_with` wraps `view` to take an extra argument. What makes it work is this:

```
// This function is unsafe and should not be called concurrently to avoid difficult bugs
fn call_view_with(callback: MyViewFn, extra: ExtraData) {
    // static mut needs to be initialized with a constant expression for some reason
    static mut static_extra: ExtraData = ExtraData::default();
    // Using mutable static requires unsafe
    unsafe {
        static_extra.data = extra.data;
    }
    static mut static_func_ptr: MyViewFn = default_callback;
    unsafe {
        static_func_ptr = callback;
    }
    // Rust allows nested function definitions. They can not capture dynamic local variables,
    // only const and static variables.
    fn view_fn(app: &nannou::App, frame: nannou::Frame) -> nannou::Frame {
        unsafe { return static_func_ptr(app, frame, &mut static_extra) }
    }
    nannou::view(view_fn);
}


impl ExtraData {
    const fn default() -> Self {
        ExtraData { data: 0 }
    }
}

fn default_callback(
    app: &nannou::App,
    frame: nannou::Frame,
    extra: &mut ExtraData,
) -> nannou::Frame {
    frame
}
```

As stated in the comments, it is not much less dangerous than defining the `static mut` globally. I suppose other functions cannot modify the data this way, at least, but you still must be careful to avoid concurrency bugs.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose, I need to report this as a bug to nannou. My version (with global static mut) uses Option<ExtraData> with `.as_ref().unwrap()` inside my view function.